# Какой календарь выбрать для IOS приложения?

Tags: ios, swift

На данный момент я использую FSCalendar в своем приложении, но его функционал ограничен.

Мне нужен календарь с событиями. Объясняю: событие по типу Action как у кнопок, что бы при изменении даты или месяца происходило определенное событие, и после нажатия определенной кнопки, которая расположена на этой же странице - данная дата помечалась на календаре. Возможно я чего-то не знаю про FSCalendar, но все что я нашел - не работает для меня.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: "Какой календарь выбрать для iOS приложения?" - нативный DatePicker, кастомные ненативные календари - user hostile, простите, если комментарий Вам не нравится.

Comment: @IgorR. можно ли настроить DatePicker, что бы в нем подсвечивались определенные даты?

Comment: @IgorR. поискал в интернете, и вроде бы нельзя каким-либо образом помечать даты...

Comment: @IgorR. DatePicker это не календарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `FSCalendar` даты можно отмечать, используя метод его `dataSource` (нужно установить свойство `dataSource` в коде или интерфейс билдере). Вот пример как отметить выбранную в пикере дату. Также советую заглянуть в `FSCalendar.h` для ознакомления с другими возможностями кастомизации

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var calendar: FSCalendar!
    @IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    
    private var selectedDate: Date?

    @IBAction func applyDateButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectedDate = datePicker.date
        calendar.reloadData()
    }

}

extension ViewController: FSCalendarDataSource {
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        guard let selectedDate = selectedDate else {
            return 0
        }
        
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        let dateWithoutTime = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)
        let selectedDateWithoutTime = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: selectedDate)
        
        if dateWithoutTime == selectedDateWithoutTime {
            return 1
        }
        
        return 0
    }
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @scgmitd9, кажется, вы мой ангел хранитель. В данном примере ведь нельзя обойтись без DatePicker для создания события да?

Comment: @Kirzzz смотря что вам нужно. Вопрос был про отметку в данном календаре, а дата `selectedDate` может быть откуда угодно - из пикера, из базы и тд

Comment: Поскольку мне нужно, что бы при переключении дня показывались события которые принадлежат этому дню ( например - 10.09.2018 - день рождение Мамы, 11.12.2019 - новый год и тд ). События проставляются заранее в календаре и далее хранятся в массиве. Следовательно после выбора даты в календаре которой не принадлежат события, мне нужно очищать поле с событием с возможностью создания нового и помечать это на календаре ( помечать через dataSource, это я понял )

Comment: @Kirzzz и в чем трудность?

Comment: в том, что нужно назначить какую то функцию на изменение даты в календаре, а в нем нет поля action для связи.

Comment: @Kirzzz если нужно отследить изменение даты, то есть метод `- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date atMonthPosition:(FSCalendarMonthPosition)monthPosition` в делегате

Comment: еще у меня ошибка "Use of unresolved identifier 'selectedDate'" (переменную selectedDate объявил как в примере )

Comment: Извиняюсь, я не доглядел, ошибки нет

Comment: Господи, все заработало! Огромное вам спасибо за наводку на didSelectDate

Comment: @Kirzzz на здоровье